# Update permalinks wordpress via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, flush

Ive just created a new custom post type on the wordpress website of a client. However the original author of the template disabled the 'settings' menu in the Wordpress Dashboard, so I cant update the permalinks through the dashboard. I can't seem to find the location where he could've disabled it, so im now looking for alternatives.

1) I downloaded a lot of the server to find the "remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );" line of code, but as said i cant find it.

2) I've heard of the flush_rewrite_rules(); functions but im a bit sceptical to use it as I'm not 100% sure what it does and dont want to screw up existing pages on their website.

Any insight or advice on any of the two topics?

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this in you functions.php and run the website once, then you're free to remove it.

```
function custom_rewrite_rules(){
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
```